# How to add padding or margin only to the layout container in Angular ngMaterial?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, flexbox, angular-material

When I add `layout-margin` or `layout-padding` to a layout container this adds margin/padding around each `flex` child element and to the container itself.

Example:

```
<div layout="row" layout-margin>
  <div flex>Parent layout and this element have margins.</div>
</div>
```

[image: flex with margins]

I want to add margins to the the container and not to the childrens of the container.

[image: margins to container only]

Is there a predefined class in Material Design to add padding or margin to the layout container without adding them to the childrens inside the layout container?

Answer (score 7):

You can create class parent for container and write css as follows.

```css
.container {
   margin : 20px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Uhhhmmm I think he means using ngMaterial not random CSS

Answer (score 2):

Please try this ,

```html
<div layout="row" class=md-margin>
  <div flex>Parent layout and this element have margins.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

zps215 has the best answer, even though it's not using ngMaterial the effect you're looking for is best solved using normal CSS. However the better solution would be to use padding on the parent container rather than margin.

```css
.container {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

However, if you really really need it solved with ngMaterial you could wrap your markup in another div and add layout-margin to it.

```
<div layout-margin>
  <div layout="row">
    <div flex>Parent layout and this element have margins.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This would get the same desired effect, though it might get confusing to anyone who adds children to that div as they would get a margin as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd want to use: `class="md-padding"` on your parent container.